# Exporting class type containing multiple values

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, export

I wrote some code [here](http://pastebin.com/xEDXKF05) that takes data from a .JSON file and turns it into an stringified object.

I need to export the *Source* and *Destination* classes here:

```
class Source {
    constructor(source_address, source_lat, source_lng, scan_type) {
        this.source_address = source_address;
        this.source_lat = source_lat;
        this.source_lng = source_lng;
    }
};

class Destination {
    constructor(dest_address, dest_lat, dest_lng, scan_type) {
        this.dest_address = dest_address;
        this.dest_lat = dest_lat;
        this.dest_lng = dest_lng;
        this.scan_type = scan_type;
    }
};
```

that I initialize like so:

```
//Initialize Source
obj.forEach(block => {
    //initialize Values
    var sourceClass = new Source(block.source_address, block.source_lat, block.source_lng, block.scan_type);
});
...
//Initialize Destination
obj.forEach(block => {
    //initialize Destination
    var destinationClass = new Destination(block.dest_address, block.dest_lat, block.dest_lng, block.scan_type);
});
```

into a separate JavaScript file.

I've tried using module.export(), and "requiring" my javascript file, but nothing seems to work.

How can I export my Source and Destination class with all it's values to another Javascript file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your module:

```
exports.Source = Source;
exports.Destination = Destination;
```

Using it:

```
var mod = require("yourmodule");
var Source = mod.Source;
var Destination = mod.Destination;
```

If you're using ES2015 (even though ES2015 modules aren't supported by NodeJS yet), you can use destructuring syntax to simplify use a bit:

```
let { Source, Destination } = require("yourmodule");
```

*(Which looks similar to what `import` will look when ES2015 modules are supported [but works fundamentally differently].)*

Comment: Thanks! I was planning on running this through babel first. I tried something similar to your solution, but didn't have any luck. Perhaps I made some mistake, I'll try this out when I get back to my desk soon!

Comment: @Bryce: Babel will integrate with Browserify or Webpack (or just Node's module system) if you like.